# how can i open def feeds(): by doubleclicking the item of treeview 'create?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, bind, double-click

i can t open the function feeds() by doublecklicking item create ration of treeview.I am not so good at programming ,i am learning now to working with tkinter.I think that i analyzed with a few words my problem.Tkanks in advance!!!

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText



screen = tk.Tk()
screen.state("zoomed")
screen.title("TEST")



tabControl = ttk.Notebook(screen)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab1, text='Ration')
tabControl.grid(padx=20,pady=40,ipadx=250 ,ipady=100)

ttk.Label(tab1, text="Animal Categories", font=16).place(relx=0.086,rely=0.15,anchor='center')
treeview = ttk.Treeview(tab1)
treeview.grid(padx=30, pady=150, ipadx=200, ipady=85)
treeview.insert('', 'end', 'i1', text='Lactating ewes')
treeview.insert(parent='i1',index='end',text='create')



def feeds():
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    text = ScrolledText(root, width=50, height=10)
    text.pack()
    list=['FEED1','FEED2','FEED3']
    
    for i in range (len(list)):
        cb = tk.Checkbutton(text, text=(list[i]), bg='white', anchor='w')
        i=i+1
        text.window_create('end', window=cb)
        text.insert('end', '\n')
    root.mainloop()


screen.mainloop()`


i can t open the function feeds() by doublecklicking item create ration of treeview


'''

from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText



screen = tk.Tk()
screen.state("zoomed")
screen.title("TEST")



tabControl = ttk.Notebook(screen)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab1, text='Ration')
tabControl.grid(padx=20,pady=40,ipadx=250 ,ipady=100)

ttk.Label(tab1, text="Animal Categories", font=16).place(relx=0.086,rely=0.15,anchor='center')
treeview = ttk.Treeview(tab1)
treeview.grid(padx=30, pady=150, ipadx=200, ipady=85)
treeview.insert('', 'end', 'i1', text='Lactating ewes')
treeview.insert(parent='i1',index='end',text='create')



def feeds():
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    text = ScrolledText(root, width=50, height=10)
    text.pack()
    list=['FEED1','FEED2','FEED3']
    
    for i in range (len(list)):
        cb = tk.Checkbutton(text, text=(list[i]), bg='white', anchor='w')
        i=i+1
        text.window_create('end', window=cb)
        text.insert('end', '\n')
    root.mainloop()


screen.mainloop()
```

i am trying the commands below with little differences but nothing happens.Thanks in advance!!!

```
class App:
   
        treeview.bind("<Double-1>", self.OnDoubleClick)
     

    def OnDoubleClick(self, choose_feeds):
        item = treeview.selection()[0]
      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

Comment: Sorry your question isn't clear...

Comment: You are using duplicated  tk.Tk(). Use this root = tk.Tk()  and mainloop() to write entire script

Comment: Good morning,thanks for your answer,I did this because I want def choose_feeds not in the central screen (frame)

Comment: I want  the function def choose_feeds run when I doubleclick "create" (item of treeview,parent i1,index=0).

Comment: I don't see choose_feeds() function.